# applicationIconBadgeNumber - How to display with empty value?

Tags: iphone, sdk, notifications, uiapplication

How to I make a red number indicators without any number inside it ? Or anyone have any ideas that help user know if the App is running on background or not ?

Thanks for helping me

Tung Do

Answer (score 0):

The basic badge turns off when set to zero. Generally on iOS, apps are suspended as opposed to killed (though they can be configured to the latter, most aren't). I don't think the badge is what you want here.